# Ruby blank line in file won't remove

Tags: ruby, line, gsub

I must've browsed every solution on StackOverflow, nothing seems to be removing the blank line's from text file which looks like this:

```
google
yahoo

facebook

reddit
```

Amongst other sources, I've tried:

```
File.foreach("file.txt") { |line|
  line.gsub(/^$\n/, '')
}
```

and

```
replace = text.gsub /^$\n/, ''
File.open("file.txt", "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
```

However, these aren't working. I'm tearing my hair out, it seems that there is no native Nokogiri method, and regular expressions aren't working either.

Comment: try this: line.gsub("\n", '')

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces? Try also the m-mode. Try `line.gsub(/^\s*$/m, '')`

Answer (score 2):

How about you check if it is empty instead?

```
out = File.new("out.txt", "w")

File.foreach("file.txt") { |line|
  out.puts line unless line.chomp.empty?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use below one liner to delete all blank lines from a file

```
file = "/tmp/hello.log"
File.write(file, File.read(file).gsub(/\n+/,"\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the gsub a little bit and it will work

```
File.foreach("file.txt"){|line|
  line.gsub("\n", '')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source_file = '/hello.txt'
new_file = File.new('/hello_new.txt')
File::open(new_file,'w') do |file|
  File::open(source_file,'r').each(sep="\n") do |line|
    file << line unless line.gsub("\n",'').length == 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[String#squeeze](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) is nice for this. Here it reduces series of line-ends to a single line-end.

```
open("out.txt", "w") {|out| open("test.txt") {|in| out << in.read.squeeze("\n")}}
```